# How to allow the banner to be editable via front end?

Tags: 6, theming

In the [BlueMasters 6.x theme](https://drupal.org/project/bluemasters/), the banner is hard-coded inside `page-front-tpl.php`:

```
<div id="banner" class="clearfix">
  <?php //print $banner;?>
  <div class="main_view">
    <div class="window">
      <div class="image_reel">
        <a href="event-1"><img src="sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/slide-image-1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="event-2"><img src="sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/slide-image-2.jpg"></a>
        <a href="event-3"><img src="sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/slide-image-3.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="descriptions">
        <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> Event One </div>
        <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> Event Two </div>
        <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> Event Three </div>
      </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="paging" style="display: block;">
      <a rel="1" href="#" class="">1</a>
      <a rel="2" href="#" class="">2</a>
      <a rel="3" href="#" class="">3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div><!--banner-->
```

How can I expose the above `banner` `div` such that it reads from a particular `page`'s (Full-HTML) content, instead of hard-coded. Such that the user can change the banner without FTP/SSH access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why it is set up this way, but I'll hazard a guess that it was set up as a demo/starting point for a slide show.  Regardless, from a quick look at the bluemasters.info file, there is a banner region defined, so if you change the above to be just:

```
<div id="banner" class="clearfix">
  <?php print $banner;?>
</div>
```

eg, remove the // that is commenting out $banner and remove all of the hardcoded stuff under it, your front page will now have an extensible region in it called banner.

Then, from the Blocks UI, you will be able to place blocks in there.  If you want to grab something from a specific node, you can easily do that from there, or programmatically via a small custom module.

If what you are wanting is a slide show, you can delve into this theme and figure out what it's looking for, or utilize any of the numerous Views slide show modules out there and then assign their resulting block to this region.

Comment: I uncommented `print $banner;`, moved the `main_view div` code into a new block named `Slide`, placed the `Slide` block inside the Banner region. So the designer can edit the block content instead of the `page-front.tpl.php`. There is some defect in the animation, but that is another question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75452/how-to-print-banner-without-div.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways without coding:

- Use [Nodeblock](https://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) to create nodes for banners. Give users right to edit nodes and place them where you need them as a blocks.
- Use Views to create a block displaying (random?) node of content type banner. Give your users right to create, delete and edit them.

You could also use [Advertisement](https://drupal.org/project/ad) module, but for a simple case like this it's an overkill, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your custom module that will allow user to change the banners via back-end process.

- Steps :

  1. Create Content Type for Banner
  2. Add image field in content type banner
  3. Create custom block in your module
  4. Load all the nodes related to node type banner using node_load_multiple and then just use foreach for iterating through
     your images fields .
  5. Adjust your theme and css in your block and return that output.
  6. Create Region for theme and render that region in page--front.tpl.php.
  7. And finally enable block in that region.