# How to print $banner; without <div>?

Tags: 6, blocks, theming

After [moving some animation code from page-front.tpl.php to a block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75350/how-to-allow-the-banner-to-be-editable-via-front-end/), the paging animation is broken.

Good:

[image]

Broken:

[image]

The slide code is:

```
<div id="banner" class="clearfix">
    <div class="main_view">
    <div class="window">
      <div class="image_reel">
        <a href="event-1"><img src="sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/slide-image-1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="event-2"><img src="sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/slide-image-2.jpg"></a>
        <a href="event-3"><img src="sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/slide-image-3.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="descriptions">
        <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> Event One </div>
        <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> Event Two </div>
        <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> Event Three </div>
      </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="paging" style="display: block;">
      <a rel="1" href="#" class="">1</a>
      <a rel="2" href="#" class="">2</a>
      <a rel="3" href="#" class="">3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!--banner-->
```

When I move the above code into a block and output via `print $banner;`, there is some extra `<div>` which breaks the animations:

```
<div id="banner" class="clearfix">
<div id="block-block-4" class="clear-block block block-block">
<div class="content">
    <div class="main_view">
    <div class="window">
      <div class="image_reel">
        <a href="event-1"><img src="sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/slide-image-1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="event-2"><img src="sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/slide-image-2.jpg"></a>
        <a href="event-3"><img src="sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/slide-image-3.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="descriptions">
        <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> Event One </div>
        <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> Event Two </div>
        <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> Event Three </div>
      </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="paging" style="display: block;">
      <a rel="1" href="#" class="">1</a>
      <a rel="2" href="#" class="">2</a>
      <a rel="3" href="#" class="">3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!--banner-->
```

Is it possible to force `print $banner;` to output the raw content of a block, without the `<div id="block-block-4" class="clear-block block block-block">` and `<div class="content">`?

Comment: Did you try making a new block.tpl.php file, or one that matches your usage?  See [this page on drupal](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) for more help.  You could probably get away with just modifying the template file for blocks. edit: updated link

Comment: I tried removing all `<div>`s from `block.tpl.php` and leave only: `<?php print $block->content ?>`. However, the paging buttons are still position wrong. I compared the html source and there is no extra `<div>`s. I am wondering why...

Comment: can you check to see which template file it is using, you can do this with the [Devel Themer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module.  Did you ensure you edited the block tpl from the active theme as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** *Changes made to work for Drupal 6 as your tag states 6.*

It looks like the system is using the standard `block.tpl.php` with this code:

```
<div id="block-<?php print $block->module .'-'. $block->delta; ?>" class="clear-block block block-<?php print $block->module ?>">

<?php if (!empty($block->subject)): ?>
  <h2><?php print $block->subject ?></h2>
<?php endif;?>

  <div class="content"><?php print $block->content ?></div>
</div>
```

What you need to do is add another block template file, and take away the `<div>` tags you want to eliminate.  To do this, add a template named `block-module-delta.tpl.php` to your active theme.

For `block-module-delta.tpl.php`

- Module = the module that's creating the block (views, block, etc)
- Delta = the internal id assigned to the block

So if the block module made the block, and it has an id of 4, you'd name the template file `block-block-4.tpl.php`, and you'd put this PHP/HTML in the template file:

```
<?php if (!empty($block->subject)): ?>
  <h2><?php print $block->subject ?></h2>
<?php endif;?>

<?php print $block->content ?>
```

Notice how I eliminated the `<div id="block-block-4" class="clear-block block block-block"> and <div class="content">` from the template.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [inertialmedia's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/75453/1244), now I found the root of the problem. When I move the paging code from `.php` to block:

```
<div class="paging" style="display: block;">
  <a rel="1" href="#" class="">1</a>
  <a rel="2" href="#" class="">2</a>
  <a rel="3" href="#" class="">3</a>
</div>
```

The html generated is:

```
<div class="paging" style="display: block;">
  <a rel="1" href="#" class="">1</a><br />
  <a rel="2" href="#" class="">2</a><br />
  <a rel="3" href="#" class="">3</a>
</div>
```

`print $block->content` converts (some) line breaks to `<br />` and so the paging buttons will be ok if I join the lines together:

```
<div class="paging" style="display: block;">
  <a rel="1" href="#" class="">1</a> <a rel="2" href="#" class="">2</a> <a rel="3" href="#" class="">3</a>
</div>
```