# Why print $block->content sometimes converts line break to <br /> but sometimes does not?

Tags: 6, blocks

During [debugging of a sliding animation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75452/how-to-print-banner-without-div), I found that `print $block->content` sometimes convert line breaks to `<br />`.

The following code in a `block`:

```
<div class="paging" style="display: block;">
  <a rel="1" href="#" class="">1</a>
  <a rel="2" href="#" class="">2</a>
  <a rel="3" href="#" class="">3</a>
</div>
```

is output in HTML as:

```
<div class="paging" style="display: block;">
  <a rel="1" href="#" class="">1</a><br />
  <a rel="2" href="#" class="">2</a><br />
  <a rel="3" href="#" class="">3</a>
</div>
```

*Note:* there are two `<br />`.

While the following code in a `block` (`<a>` `</a>` surrounded by `<div>` `</div>`):

```
<div class="paging" style="display: block;">
  <div><a rel="1" href="#" class="">1</a></div>
  <div><a rel="2" href="#" class="">2</a></div>
  <div><a rel="3" href="#" class="">3</a></div>
</div>
```

is output in HTML as:

```
<div class="paging" style="display: block;">
<div><a rel="1" href="#" class="">1</a></div>
<div><a rel="2" href="#" class="">2</a></div>
<div><a rel="3" href="#" class="">3</a></div>
</div>
```

*Note:* there is no `<br />`.

How can I disable line break to `<br />` conversion when printing block content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be due to the `input format` you are using for the block's content region.

Assuming you are using the default input format (`id 1`), the filter option `Line break converter` is probably enabled. See admin page: /admin/settings/filters/1

You can uncheck this setting in the default input format or you can use a different input format by clicking on the `Input format` fieldset under the `Block body` content region.

If you do not have any other input formats, you can add a new one that does not use this `Line break converter` setting here: /admin/settings/filters/add

**Note**: Being able to configure or add any input format requires the `administer filters` permission from the `filter` module.

Comment: Why the `filter` converts line break for text around `<a>` `</a>` but not for text around `<div>` `</div`, both are in the same `block`.

Comment: `<div>`s will already be displayed on separate lines as they are by default rendered as `display: block`.